# Anchor in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has some dates on it. I would like to go directy to a specific entry (i.e. "today's date") in my tableview when I open it.

That means I want to have the past dates already scrolled down and the first line I see is the one with today's date.  How can I do that?

Thanks,

Laurent

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `UITableView`?
Try this:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```